# How to : Store app's data and prevent third party from accessing it (like a normal .txt file)

Tags: c++, c

thank you for considering answering me.

I am trying to create an app that would keep information stored in it to use it again when the program launches again, without allowing the user to access it like in a usual text file.
(I know this might look pretty basic, but hey I'm starting, so I don't know much... :( )

It's final purpose would be for a story based game where you can make choices that affect the story, so I don't want anyone to be able to cycle through the possibilities with only a slight change in a text file.

Comment: You could try using a binary format which is technically still possible to modify, but much harder.

Comment: Store/retrieve  the data as encrypted data. Far too broad for an answer here.

Comment: Oh yeah, didn't even consider that. Thanks.